# PHP CLASS Undefined variable (But it is defined)

Tags: php, class, variables, null, undefined

I just can't figure out why this error is even showing up:

> Notice: Undefined variable: authTime in /.../classname.class.php on line 33

```
class ClassName {

private $authTime = null;


const API_URL       = '...';
const CLIENT_ID     = '...';
const CLIENT_SECRET = '...';

private static $TOKEN     = NULL;


public function __construct() {
$this->_authTime = $authTime; // <----- Line 33
if(!self::$TOKEN OR $this->AuthTime('GET') > 3600 OR !$this->_authTime) {
  self::authorise();
}
}

public function getAuthTime() {
    return $this->_authTime; // Returns NULL
}
```

Comment: Where is it defined? It is use right after the declaration of the constructor? but never declared. And why the underscore before the property? `_authTime`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17688430 why is that edit adding the rant BACK in??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see `$authTime` is not defined within the constructor. I think you want to do:

```
$this->_authTime = $this->authTime;
```

Comment: Ok... :o That got rid of the error, but when I try to specify the value of that variable `$this->authTime = time();` I get the same error. **Edit:** My bad, i was calling `$this->` in a static function. Thanks for the help. My hero! :D

Comment: You are welcome. Im glad I could help :)